# Autofac - auto registration error : No constructors can be found with 'Public binding flags'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, autofac

This is my Global.asax.cs

```
public void RegisterContainersUsingAutofac()
    {
        //http://elegantcode.com/2009/01/07/ioc-libraries-compared/
        //http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25380/Dependency-Injection-with-Autofac
        //https://code.google.com/p/autofac/
        //http://api.autofac.org/
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterModelBinders(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();
        //builder.RegisterType<AuthenticationService>().As<IAuthenticationService>();
        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

        //builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(SecurityService).Assembly).
        //      Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service")).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        builder.RegisterType(typeof(UnitOfWork)).As(typeof(IUnitOfWork)).InstancePerLifetimeScope()
            .OnRelease(x =>{((IUnitOfWork)x).Commit();});

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(UserRepository).Assembly).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository")).AsImplementedInterfaces();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(SecurityService).Assembly).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service")).AsImplementedInterfaces();

        IContainer container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    }
```

And i'm having the following error:
    No constructors on type 'AppBase.Service.UserService' can be found with 'Public binding flags'.

I registered my implemented interfaces of repositories and services, but where did i go wrong? It breaks at the following.

This is my userService

```
 public interface IUserService
{
    int Login(string userNameOrEmail, string password, out int errorcode, out int timeout);
    bool Register(string userName, string password, string email, string country, string language, out int errorCode);

    bool Register(User user, out int errorCode);
    bool ResetPassword(string username, string email, string oldPassword, string newPassword, out int errorCode);

    void DeleteUser(string userName);
}
public class UserService : IUserService
{
      private readonly IUserRepository userRepository;
     private UserService(IUserRepository _userRepository)
    {
        userRepository = _userRepository;

    }
    //other methods ...

}
```

This is my error:

```
 [DependencyResolutionException: No constructors on type 'AppBase.Service.UserService' can be found with 'Public binding flags'.]
 Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +261
 Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +91
 Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +135
 Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +434
 Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +61
 Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CanSupplyValue>b__0() +68
 Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate() +201
             Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +499
 Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +91
 Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +135
 Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +434
 Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +52
 Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +115
 Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +300
 Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) +103
 Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +218
 Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +64
 Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType) +43
 Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType) +49
 System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +51

 [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'AppBase.Web.Controllers.AccountController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
 System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +182
 System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +80
 System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +74
 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +232
 System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass6.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2() +49
 System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a() +13
 System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
 System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
  System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Func`1 func) +124
 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +98
 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
 System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8968180
 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'm not sure why `UserService` has a private constructor. Is there a reason for this?

By defining a constructor, the default constructor `public UserService()` is no longer generated.

Autofac will only inject into public constructors, of which you now have none. It should work if you change it to public.

Comment: Durr--this made me feel a bit less intelligent :).

Comment: Gah! So obvious once you spot it.

Answer (score 3):

@HackedByChinese answer is correct.

Re-sharper suggested that I make a class in my service layer abstract. This also prevents a default public constructor from being generated. This bugged me for a little bit so I thought it might help someone else.